# D&D Encounters Dark Sun Season

Tags: dnd-4e, dark-sun, dnd-encounters

I've stepped up to run one of the local Encounters tables for this season.  However I don't have adventure chapters 1 & 2.  What has happened in the story up until now?

Comment: Voted to close as this is too localized to a certain point in time (which is passed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a whole lot, really.

SPOILERS FOLLOW

> The player characters' caravan was wrecked by a storm.
>   
>   The storm chased the players for a ways (it seemed to be driven by some intelligence).
>   
>   There was a dialog encounter with a fire elemental, but my group didn't get much out of it.
>   
>   The players eventually take shelter in a cave system, which contains a crypt. They defeat a corrupted elemental spirit, meet some non-corrupted spirits, and are charged with spreading the word that arcane energy isn't always evil.
>   
>   The second chapter ends with them leaving the cave system, and being confronted (captured) by a horde of halflings.

Those are the high points that I remember from being a player. I'm probably missing a hook or two.

Answer (score 1):

There many great blogs on people detailing their groups adventures.  Try obsidian portal.  Also a quick Google search got me this:

LINK TO SPOILERS

> http://dungeonsmaster.com/2010/06/dd-encounters-dark-sun-week-2/

which is a pretty clean summary.  Happy DM'ing